# Matching gnmap Output in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the following line in a gnmap file:

23/open/tcp//telnet

and I'd like it to out put just the port number. Sometimes the port is 23. Othertimes, its 2323 or 6000, or some other number.

I've tried this code, but the regex will not match properly:

```
import re

class REMatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, matchstring):
        self.matchstring = matchstring

    def match(self,regexp):
        self.rematch = re.match(regexp, self.matchstring)
        return bool(self.rematch)

    def group(self,i):
        return self.rematch.group(i)

gnmap_file = "telnet.gnmap"

with open(gnmap_file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        m = REMatcher(line)
        if m.match("([0-9])*\/open\/tcp\/\/telnet"):
            print m.group(1)
```

I think I'm missing something in the regex. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `([0-9])*` to `([0-9]*)` and if possible get rid of your weird wrapper class around the re module.

Comment: I didnt noticed I did this, but I did try it and I'm still not getting matches.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print(repr(line))`? Is there perhaps some leading whitespace?

Comment: Or perhaps you meant to use `re.search` rather than `re.match`?

Comment: There is a leading whitespace on some lines but not all. Host: 192.168.1.38 ()\tPorts: 7/open/tcp//echo?///, 9/open|filtered/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 13/open/tcp//daytime?///, 21/open/tcp//ftp?///, 22/open/tcp//ssh?///, 23/open/tcp//telnet?///, 25/open|filtered/tcp//tcpwrapped///\n'

Comment: That pretty much did it. I used search and changed things up a bit and it worked. Thank you. Throw it as an answer and I'll accept it.